# Error sending data back to apollo server by (bad request error)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I am creating a project with React, Apollo and graphql. So far I've been successful enough to get the data back but I am not able to create (mutate) new data onto the server. Everytime I try. it gives me a 'Bad request' Error.
I am attaching the react code and the resolver for the create post. Any help would be highly appreciated.

React Code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";

import { CREATE_POST } from "../graphql/Mutation";

function WebForm(props) {
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

const [createPost, { data }] = useMutation(CREATE_POST);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {

e.preventDefault();

  createPost({
  variables: { name: username, title: title, description: description },
});
};

return (

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={formStyle}>
  <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
  <input
    style={inputStyle}
    type="text"
    value={username}
    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
  />
  <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
  <input
    style={inputStyle}
    type="text"
    value={title}
    onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
  />
  <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
  <input
    style={inputStyle}
    type="text"
    value={description}
    onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
  />
  <button type="submit" style={buttonStyle}>
    Create Post
  </button>
</form>
)
}

const buttonStyle = {
  marginTop: 10,
  padding: "5px 25px 5px 25px",
  background: "#aef359",
  outline: "none",
  border: "none",
  color: "black",
  borderRadius: 5,
};

const formStyle = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  alignItems: "center",
  width: "100%",
  justifyContent: "center",
  marginTop: 15,
};

const inputStyle = { borderRadius: 4 };

export default WebForm;
```

Resolver Code for CreatePost Mutation:

```
async createPost(_, { name, title, description }, context) {
      const newPost = new Post({
        name,
        title,
        description,
      });

      try {
        const post = await newPost.save();
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error("Failed to create post", err);
      }

      return post;
    },
```

Also the mutation query in front-end

```
const CREATE_POST = gql`
  mutation CreatePost($name: String!, $title: String!, $description: String!) {
    createPost(name: $name, title: $title, description: $description) {
      id
      Name
      title
      description
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are querying for the `Name` field instead of `name` in your `CREATE_POST` mutation. I assume `post` in your `createPost` resolver is an object that looks like this:

```
{
  id
  name
  title
  description
}
```

Field names are case sensitive. In the future for debugging, you can inspect the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools and look for the specific `graphql` request, which should be highlighted in red. You can then look at the response and extract the specific `GraphQLError` message. These messages are usually descriptive enough to know what went wrong, instead of the generic `Bad request` error message. It is usually able to catch simple typos like this in my experience and suggest the correct field name.